# cloudlinux-root disk usage error? Increasing disk size?

Tags: ssh, cpanel, cloudlinux

```
devtmpfs                      32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         32G   77M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         32G  3.2G   29G  11% /run
tmpfs                         32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cloudlinux-root   50G   43G  4.5G  91% /
none                          32G     0   32G   0% /var/lve/dbgovernor-shm
/dev/sda2                    974M  190M  718M  21% /boot
/dev/mapper/cloudlinux-home  3.9T   14G  3.7T   1% /home
/dev/loop0                   2.0G   17M  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                        6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                        6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1107
```

Here is my disk layout. My **/dev/mapper/cloudlinux-root** partition is **91%** and giving an error. Can I throttle the **cloudlinux-home** partition and add it to the **cloudlinux-root** partition? How can I do that? Will there be any problems if I do?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question appears to be about a system with an administration panel installed. These questions are [always off-topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3922/question-about-migrated-post-that-was-closed/3924#3924) here at Server Fault and may be more appropriate over at [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com). And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).